# Use session variable as object in PHP

Tags: php

Need some assistance. I am getting the following errors

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on string in......

This refers to the line on by `index.php`

```
$session->getName()
```

The code.

**index.php**

```
include 'classes/user.php';
$session = isset($_SESSION['userObj']) ? $_SESSION['userObj'] : "";
include 'login.php';

$session->getName()
```

**login.php**

```
session_start();
$user = new User();
$user->setAll($db_id,$db_fullname,$db_username,$db_rights, $db_last_login,$db);

$_SESSION['userObj'] = $user;
```

How do you pass objects correctly via session vars? I've checked on this site and its advised to do it like i have.

I know i'm not doing the else statement right on the `isset` part. Should i be doing.

```
else{ $session = new User();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `serialize()`

```
//Set object as session
$user = new User();
$_SESSION['userObj'] = serialize($user);

//Get object 
$user = unserialize($_SESSION['userObj']);
```

FYI, don't forget to write `session_start();` on first line of every page to use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Thats what fixed the issue... I had session_start(); only in login.php...
and in index.php
$user = $_SESSION['userObj'];
was below include 'login.php'...
Soon as i put include above the $user line it worked.

Thanks for the serialize part

Comment: Great, don't forget to upvote for future reference ..All the best